# Capture words in a tagged sentence with Lua patterns

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

Sample line: `('The', 'DT')('mirror', 'NN')('can', 'MD')('barely', 'RB')('contain', 'VB')('me', 'PRP')('.', '.')`

What I need:

```
The
mirror
can
barely
contain
me
.
```

Using this pattern will return the whole line and not each words (plus some clatter):

```
txt = "('The', 'DT')('mirror', 'NN')('can', 'MD')('barely', 'RB')('contain', 'VB')('me', 'PRP')('.', '.')"

for i in txt:gmatch("%('.+',") do
    print(i)
end
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you use the + modifier it matches as much as it possibly can, whereas the - does the opposite. So your code is capturing a LOT, try this instead:

```
for i in txt:gmatch("%('(.-)',") do
    print(i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` modifier is greedy, use `-` instead:

```
for i in txt:gmatch("%('(.-)',") do
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.